# What should be done when a user circumvents a quality ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, low-quality-posts

A user asked a question here on Meta about deleting his account. It was closed as a duplicate, but reading the comments I garnered that the user had been previously question banned, and was looking to delete their account so they could re-create it an ask anew.

Later, I checked their account and realized they'd done exactly this - gone were the questions and answers they'd previously posted, and the "member for" field now read "today".

If they have circumvented their ban, shouldn't something be done in that regard?

(Update: their posts are back; it appears the "new" account didn't stay that way for long)

Comment: In all seriousness, I don't think it's really that hard to circumvent the ban. There really is nothing SE (or any online community) can do to block someone who has access to multiple IPs and proxies. I'm not saying that's the case here, but getting a new IP address is often easier than asking SE to delete your account so you can start over.

Comment: In other words, there's probably no point in trying to close a loop-hole that is harder to exploit than the nuclear option of changing your IP address.

Comment: @Mysticial Loop hole or not, what about the status of the new account?

Comment: I dunno. That's up to the mods. I don't know how often this happens, but it might be rare enough to be handled on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Well, deleting your questions won't help in getting back, now will it?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Should it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you delete your questions, then you can't improve them to remove the ban...

Comment: @ColeJohnson: In practice, the number of people that manage to improve their questions enough to lift the ban is vanishingly small.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'd say most of those people are those who come to meta, or just on the edge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to work around any ban if you're determined enough.

It's also possible to just get the quality-ban *lifted* if you're determined enough to get better at writing.

I'm not overly concerned about folks who do the latter, even if they also do the former. In fact, I'll happily help anyone interested to get the ban lifted, and I'll wager plenty of folks here feel the same way.

Folks who don't improve will just end up banned again. The goal is to add enough resistance to make actual improvement pay off more in the long run.